# SQL Server -- Select a string between two known strings

Tags: sql-server, substring, charindex

I'm trying to insert into another column the database name from the TEXT column return by the following query, which was inserted into another table:

```
EXEC master..sp_readerrorlog 0,1,"Database backed up. Database:"
```

which returns

> Database backed up. Database: databaseName, creation date(time): 2014/06/13(17:49:54), pages dumped: 197581, first LSN: 488:6298:36, last LSN: 488:6314:1, number of dump devices: 4, device information: ...

Following recomandations of other posts from here, I wrote:

```
SUBSTRING([TEXT], LEN(LEFT([TEXT], CHARINDEX (': ', [TEXT]))) + 1, LEN([TEXT]) - LEN(LEFT([TEXT], 
CHARINDEX (': ', [TEXT]))) - LEN(RIGHT([TEXT], LEN([TEXT]) - CHARINDEX (', ', [TEXT]))) + 1) 
as DatabseName
```

which returns

> 'DatabaseName,' keeping the comma

I've tried to alter both `CHARINDEX parameter '+1'` without success.

Anybody has an idea on how to get rid of that comma ?

Answer (score 1):

How about this line?

```
SUBSTRING([TEXT], CHARINDEX('Database:', [TEXT]) + 10, CHARINDEX('creation date', [TEXT]) - (CHARINDEX('Database:', [TEXT]) + 12))
```

Comment: No need to search for the entire words and using large offsets, this will work just as well and is a bit shorter: `SUBSTRING([TEXT],CHARINDEX(':',[TEXT])+2, CHARINDEX(',',[TEXT]) - (CHARINDEX(':',[TEXT])+2))` +1 anyway

Comment: I didn't work either.  A collegue of mine suggest: `replace(SUBSTRING([TEXT], LEN(LEFT([TEXT], CHARINDEX (': ', [TEXT]))) + 2, LEN([TEXT]) - LEN(LEFT([TEXT], CHARINDEX (': ', [TEXT]))) - LEN(RIGHT([TEXT], LEN([TEXT]) - CHARINDEX (', ', [TEXT]))) - 0),',','')`, which works. But I still would like to know if it's possible just using `Substring` and `Charindex`.

Answer (score 0):

There is always a function for any string manipulation out there.

Oooh look what Google found!

http://www.spatialdbadvisor.com/sql_server_blog/136/string-tokenizer-for-sql-server-2008-written-in-tsql/

:)